# jquery help needed

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle, slidedown

Need a little help with a project. Take a look at

I want the red area with the football to slide up a little on hover and slide back down when done.
The red area with the football is a background of a div. Positioned absolute and bottom 0, inside a div that is relative to keep it at the bottom. Basically I want to increase the height of that div but having some issues with the code. I have tried using the slideDown method and slideToggle. I can get it to slide down a little but not sure how to increase the height of it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: How can we help you with your code when you didn't post any?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("div.bottomwrapsports").on({
    'mouseenter': function() {
        $(this).animate({ bottom: 20 });
    },
    'mouseleave': function() {
        $(this).animate({ bottom: 0 });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for all the help. Looks like I got it. Any clue on how I can get it to animate only one image at a time? Right now all three go up and I understand its because they all use the same div, but wordpress dynamically creates the loop.

Comment: That did work. Thanks for the help :)  What part of that code is keeping the others from moving up? Is it the mouseenter?

Comment: No, `$(this)` in the handlers does the selection. `this` in both cases is the element that was 'mouse-entered' or 'mouse-left'. So `$(this)` is a jQuery object containing just that one element, whever one it happens to be.

Answer (score 0):

First, your `#contain` div should have `height: 67px`, not just `67`. Then, if you give `div.bottomwrapsports` a `position: absolute; bottom: 0`, you can animate that bottom property using jQuery on mouseover:

```
$("div.bottomwrapsports").animate({ bottom: 20 });  // move it 20px up
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked for sliding it up. Is there a way for it to slide back down once Im done hovering on it? I need to figure out a way so all of those elements dont slide up at once.

Comment: Do you want the red stripe to animate behind the football without moving it?

Comment: @user1525766: You probably want to animate back to `bottom: 0`. As for only animating the appropriate element, you can use some of the traversal functions to select it.